# Enable Advanced Currency Management using CLI

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

Is it possible to enable **Advanced Currency Management** (see image) using CLI? [image] I need to enable it in the scratch org. The use case is that our test classes require that Advanced Currency Management is enabled. I have sought answers across Google and nothing comes up pertaining to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some settings are still not supported as of today .You can find the list of unsupported settings [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm)

Looks like Advanced Currency (Currency Exchange Rates) is not supported and today you are out of luck .

***What are your options ?***

1. Salesforce has a pilot program called Scratch org snapshots .That allows to create a scratch org from pre configured scratch org .Seems like this is exactly what you need .
2. If you have heard of [googles puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) we could use this to run a web browser headless .Hence you can script it today to find the right setting and enable it .

Wade has a sample repo on how to approach [this](https://github.com/wadewegner/sfdx-puppeteer) .

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! By 'Scratch org snapshots' do you mean shape org?
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm

Comment: Org shape and org snapshots are two different things .My answer has url for you to reach out .

Comment: Thank you! How do you know that Currency Exchange Rates is same as Advanced Currency?

Comment: There is nothing else I could relate to except that !

Comment: I just got word from Rohit Mehta at Salesforce that "Snapshots is not available yet'

Comment: You mean not even in pilot ?

Comment: Yes. Not in pilot! He said "We've working through some kinks in the product in order to get it working. As soon as we've fixed those bugs, I will announce its availability in the Trailblazer community."

Comment: This 2019 accepted answer is now out of date and misleading - as the feature is now configurable as per the newer answer by Christopher. Can we please move the accepted answer marker to indicate this to new searchers?

Answer (score 2):

This can be turned on in the Scratch Org Definition File (the one ending scratch-def.json) for a project. Simply add Multicurrency to features, and then in currencySettings, enable multi currency and currency effective dates. When you create your scratch org, Advanced currency management will be turned on.

```
{
    "orgName": "My Scratch",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["MultiCurrency"],
    "settings": {
        "currencySettings": {
            "enableMultiCurrency":true,
            "enableCurrencyEffectiveDates":true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making this manual change, we can retrieve following Currency Setting in package xml and then can set **enableCurrencyEffectiveDates** to true.