# Exception during creation of version of unlocked package: "Field is not writeable: DatedConversionRate.IsoCode"

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, multi-currency

Trying to create a version of an unlocked package...

`sfdx force:package:version:create -p curry42 -d force-app -x --wait 10 -v multi-cur-dev-hub -f config/project-scratch-def.json -c`

... I'm getting...

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Multiple errors occurred:
> (1) Apex Test Failure: Class.CurrencyTypeManager.getDatedConversionRates: line 46, column 1
> Class.CurrencyTypeManagerTest.getDatedConversionRates: line 50, column 1 System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: DatedConversionRate.IsoCode
> (2) Apex Test Failure: Class.CurrencyTypeManager.getDatedConversionRates: line 46, column 1
> Class.CurrencyExchangeUpdaterScheduler.updateExchangeRates: line 35, column 1
> Class.CurrencyExchangeUpdaterSchedulerTest.updateExchangeRates: line 18, column 1 System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: DatedConversionRate.IsoCode
> (3) Apex Test Failure: Class.CurrencyTypeManager.getDatedConversionRates: line 46, column 1
> Class.CurrencyExchangeUpdaterScheduler.updateExchangeRates: line 35, column 1
> Class.CurrencyExchangeUpdaterScheduler.doExecute: line 25, column 1 System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: DatedConversionRate.IsoCode

The code referred to by the first of the three exceptions is:

```apex
for (CurrencyType currencyType : currencyTypes) {
    DatedConversionRate dcr = new DatedConversionRate();
    dcr.IsoCode = currencyType.IsoCode;
```

The unit test assigns 'EUR' in afore line, i.e. currencyType.IsoCode is 'EUR'. This line works well from Execute Anonymous and launched by a scheduled job on a Sandbox.

`config/project-scratch-def.json` contains the following section:

```
"features": ["MultiCurrency"],
"settings": {
    "currencySettings":{ "enableMultiCurrency": true }
}
```

It does not make reference to Advanced Currency Management, [because this is unsupported](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252269/enable-advanced-currency-management-using-cli) in scratch org definition files. (Advanced Currency Management is activated on my DevHub.)

Have I learned the hard way that Advanced Currency Management is unsupported for unlocked packages too? Or have I overlooked something?